# Проблема с курсором мыши

Tags: c++, qt

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Есть окно `QMdiSubWindow` с понавешанными на него виджетами. При перемещении курсора к любому краю внутреннего окна, он, как и положено, меняет вид на две стрелочки, которые означают возможность изменения размера окна. Однако, при возврате курсора в само окно, курсор не меняет вид обратно на обычный указатель. Но меняет при перемещении на поле заголовка окна.
У кого-то такое было?
UPD: Методом проб и ошибок выяснил, что проблема возникает после установки внутреннего виджета

```
internalWidget = new QWidget(this);
setWidget(internalWidget);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом "тыка" было найдено решение. Оставляю тут с пометкой "ответ", может кому пригодится.
Причина была в подключённом фильтре событий, точнее в возвращаемом по умолчанию значении:

```
bool CatProductsGUI::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type()==QEvent::MouseButtonRelease){
        QMouseEvent *me = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        if(object==treeGroups->viewport()){
            QModelIndex index = treeGroups->indexAt(me->pos());
            if(!index.isValid()){
                treeGroups->clearSelection();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(object, event); //<-------------
}
```

После замены `QObject` на `QMdiSubWindow` (непосредственного предка окна, содержащего фильтр событий) всё стало на свои места. Вот такая неочивидная весчь.